# Drag events not triggered

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, draggable, drag

I want to use draggable events.
So `dragStart` works perfectly, but `drag` and `dragEnd` are never triggered.

This is my HTML Element

```html
<div [ngClass]="select ? 'show-re' : 'hide-re'" *ngIf="real_estate" id="re">
```

```
document.getElementById("re").addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
    this.start = event.clientX;
    console.log(this.start);
})
document.getElementById("re").addEventListener('drag', (event) => {
    console.log(event.clientX);
})
document.getElementById("re").addEventListener('dragend', (event) => {
    console.log(this.end)
    this.end = event.clientX;
    if (this.end - this.start > 100)
        this.hideRe();
})
```

Comment: Assuming that above ts code is written in ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook, what is the value of `real_estate` variable initially and does it change? because if it does, then the element would be frequently added and removed from the DOM as the value changes. So that may cause the event listeners to be removed.

Comment: This code is initialized after `real_estate` and it never changed. All works perfectly for `dragstart` event

Comment: what is the initial value of `real_estate`? And where have you put this code? In any lifecycle or in a function which is called from a lifecycle hook?

Comment: `real_estate` is an object as {id: 12, title: "Zodiak", area: "432"}.
This function is called after `click` event on GoogleMaps' marker that it correspond to my `real_estate` marker.

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides APIs to bind directly to events generated by HTML elements. Better use these APIs so that you don't have to worry about adding/removing event listeners. You could bind to drag events like this.

```
<div [ngClass]="select ? 'show-re' : 'hide-re'" *ngIf="real_estate" id="re" (dragstart)="dragStart($event)" (drag)="onDrag($event)" (dragend)="onDragEnd($event)" draggable="true"></div>
```

In you component.ts you can define these events as

```
dragStart($event) {
  // do stuff...
}

onDrag($event) {
  // do stuff...
}

onDragEnd($event) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

Also notice I have added set draggable attribute for `div` element.

Comment: Yes I have already tried this way since I have posted my problem, but only `dragStart` works.